Deleting an entire table previously created in python-pptx
Using python-pptx, I've created a table using :
prs = Presentation()
title_only_slide_layout = prs.slide_layout[11]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_only_slide_layout)
shapes = slide.shapes
table = shapes.add_table(rows, cols, left, top, width, height).table

For some reasons (pagination), I need to be able to delete some of the table.
I have the "table" object, as I created it with the shapes.add_table().table thingy, but how can I delete it ?
Thanks !
